# Electron React TypeScript window.require("fs") returns 'any'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, electron, require

I'm using this to enable node access in my component.

```
 const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      nodeIntegrationInWorker: true,
      nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: true,
    }
```

and

```
const fs = window.require("fs");
```

to access fs. It compiles and runs fine, but window.require("fs") returns 'any' and I not only lost auto complete but the code is marked in red.
Any way to make it typed?

installing node types didn't help